# Opportunities and Contracts - ideas welcome!

Tags: reporting, opportunity, custom-report-type, contracts

Morning all,

I would like to pilfer your collective brains if possible. I've also asked the question on the Salesforce Ideas Exchange but thought it was best to double up.

In my org, when we have a Closed Won Opportunity, there should be a Contract created against the Account that is a record of the sales we're just agreed.

What I want to do is report on Opportunities and associated Contracts. Basically, Dave closed a deal on Thursday, process dictates he should start the contracts page straight away. I want to be able to run a report the next week showing all Opportunities won the week before with their applicable contract page reference. I've created some new Look Up fields on both Opps and Contracts to record the reference numbers/names but they aren't showing up in my reporting suite.

I've created a custom report type linking Opportunities with Contracts and it runs but the data it returns is inaccurate. For example, an Account could have 3 different opportunities which require 3 different contracts. The current report just associates one of the contracts to all the opportunities and I can't figure out what link the system uses to determine which contract relates to which opportunity. There is also the case where an acocunt has one Opp with one Contract and the report only returns a null value.

Can anybody suggest anything that might help with this?

Comment: What about a lookup field on the opportunity to the contract then a trigger on the contract object to update the matching opportunity, assuming a couple fields would be uniquely the same like contract start date and product type.

Comment: I've added the lookup fields and I know have a Contracts related list in Opportunities, and visa versa. I got a little bit hopeful that we could now recognise them as linked but when I ran my Opps and Contracts custom report, it doesn't pull back the contract details. It's really quite bizarre.

Comment: Forgot to add that the fields are manually updated at the moment. My ability with Apex to encode new classes and triggers is pretty much non existant so that's something for the future.